# Examples for a kind of "set family hitting" problem

Tags: reference-request, scheduling, set-covering

Given a ground set, say $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and a collection of subset families $\mathcal F_i\subseteq 2^{[n]}$, $i=1,2,\dots,m$, I want to select $m$ sets $B_i\in\mathcal F_i$ such that the cardinality of the union $B_1\cup B_2\cup\dots\cup B_m$ is minimized. In other words, I want to hit each of the families $\mathcal F_i$ touching as few elements of the ground set as possible.

From [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/44197/15637) over at cstheory, I learnt that the general problem is very hard to approximate (reduction from the Min-Rep problem introduced in  [Kortsarz, Guy. "On the hardness of approximating spanners." Algorithmica **30**(2001): 432-450](http://www.crab.rutgers.edu/~guyk/pub/hard/nabs.pdf)).

On the other hand, the following scheduling problem can be interpreted as a very very special case which can be solved efficiently: We want to schedule a set of jobs indexed by $i$ (given by earliest start time $r_i$, latest completion time $d_i$  and processing time $p_i$) on a single machine of infinite capacity, and the objective is to minimize the total busy time of the machine. In this setting, the family $\mathcal F_i$ would just be the set of intervals $\{[r_i,r_i+p_i-1],[r_i+1,r_i+p_i],\dots,[d_i-p_i+1,d_i]\}$ (Rohit Khandekar, Baruch Schieber, Hadas Shachnai, and Tami Tamir. “Real-time scheduling
to minimize machine busy times”. Journal of Scheduling **18** (2015), p. 561-573, doi:[10.1007/s10951-014-0411-z](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10951-014-0411-z))

I'd be interested to learn about any other special cases of the problem with structured families $\mathcal F_i$ which may have been considered in an OR context.